# RoR, destroy the object my clicking ob the button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following structure:

```
<% if @uploads%>
<br class="clear" />
<br />

<% @uploads.each do |file| %>



    <div class="file_information"> 

      <p><%= file.file_name %></p>



      <td class="Chip_info">
      <a href="<%=file.info%>" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Info</a>    
      </td>

      <td class="Pic">
      <a href="<%=file.image%>" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Pic</a>    
      </td>

      <td class="Hist">
      <a href="<%=file.hist%>" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Hist</a>    
      </td>

      <td class="Hist2">
      <a href="<%=file.hist2%>" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">His2</a>    
      </td>


        <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger"  data-url="<%=file.destroy%>"> 
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>

        </button>

      </td> 



    </div>
  <%end%>
<%else%>

<br class="clear" />
<br />
<%end%>
```

The problem is that while running it, it destroys all objects automatically without me clicking on the button. Is it possible somehow to list uploads and only by clicking on the button, the corresponding upload will be deleted (destroy action will be called) and not all of uploads?

Thanks in advance

**edit**

I use this [example for file upload](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
He uses followint to delete the file:

model:

```
"delete_url" => upload_path(self)
```

view:

```
 <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger"  data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
          <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>

        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
      </td>
```

So I tried

```
data-url="<%=file.upload_path(self)%>">
```

but it doesnt work, so I printed file.upload_path(self) from a controller and got this:

```
/uploads/%23%3CUploadsController:0xaf61b34%3E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper that generates a form containing one button:

```
def button_to_delete_file(file)
  form_tag file_path(file), :method => :delete, :style => "display:inline;" do
    button_tag :class => "btn btn-mini btn-danger" do
      content_tag :i, " ", :class => "icon-trash icon-white"
    end
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
<%= button_to_delete_file(file) %>
```

Comment: It showed me an error: undefined method `button_to_delete_file' for #<#<Class:0xb321f94>:0xa5615d0>):. but I looked as well on the class of the file.It is Uploads, the right class

Comment: @Katja this method should be placed in `app/helpers/uploads_helper.rb` inside `UploadsHelper` module.

Comment: @Ilya_Khokhryakov I have all my buttons on one line, but it seems that yours is at the new line and I cannot find out how to place it on my line with the others

Comment: @Katja I think this happens because button is wrapped in `form` tag. Adding `display:inline` should fix it (see the updated code).

Answer (score 0):

In the button

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger"  data-url="<%=file.destroy%>">
```

your `data_url` is not an url. When the file is executed, everything inside `<% %>` is executed, so `file.destroy` is called.

Replace `file.destroy` by the corresponding URL (something that looks like `file_destroy_path(id)`) and it should work.

Comment: I guess it should be file.file_path(self) but when I click on the button, nothing happens

Comment: @Katja No, there's *very* probably the word `destroy` in the path. Run in the console `rake routes`, you'll see the names of all the available paths. Look for the one besides the `destroy` action on the type of your `file` object

Comment: @Katja I also think that for your view to send a `DELETE` request (like the one you need) you have to put the button inside a form

Comment: it shows me     DELETE     (/:locale)/uploads/:id(.:format)  uploads#destroy

Comment: So, I have found out, it should be file.file_path(file), but still it doesnt destroy the object